# I can't make my Promise to properly reject with a new Error message, caught from a try/catch

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, try-catch

I have a Promise method that parses links from the web. It returns an Object which I try to access a `link` key from, but when this Object is empty, it somehow skips the `if` I have to check its length, causing a scandalous error. Below the codes.

First, the method that is a Promise to parse the links:

```
* parseReporter() {
  const article = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    parser.parseURL(`https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/${this.googleAlertsUrlId}/${this.reporterUrlId}`, (err, parsed) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(new Error(err))
      }

      if (parsed.feed.entries.length === 0) {
        reject(new Error('Nothing to parse'))
      }

      const link = parsed.feed.entries[0].link
      const betterLink = link.substring(42, link.indexOf('&ct='))

      mercury.parse(betterLink).then((data) => {
        resolve(data)
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(new Error(err))
      })
    })
  })

  return article
}
```

And then, here's the method that calls this `parseReporter()`:

```
* _getLastestNews(userReporter) {
  const reportersOperation = new ReportersOperation()

  reportersOperation.googleAlertsUrlId = userReporter.url.split('/')[3]
  reportersOperation.reporterUrlId = userReporter.url.split('/')[4]

  try {
    return yield reportersOperation.parseReporter()
  } catch (e) {
    this.addError(HTTPResponse.STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.message)

    return false
  }
}
```

The error is caused when it tries to access `link` from `parsed.feed.entries[0]`. I've already logged out the `length`, and I confirmed to do work and show a number, but it insists on skipping it. Am I doing something wrong with the Promise it `try/catch` themselves?

Comment: I would recommend the first two calls to `reject` should be `return reject` - because reject doesn't "stop" the rest of the code from running ... therefore, the reject for `length === 0` is called, but then the code goes on to try and use `...[0].link` - which throws an error - which doesn't get "handled" by the wonders of the internals of the Promise code

Comment: You mean, in the two first `if`, to `reject` the `parsed`?

Comment: no ... I said put the word **return** before the word **reject** - so that the code after it isn't executed - because **reject** doesn't **return** from a function

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Please, write an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reject` doesn't "stop" or "return" from a function like `return`

Therefore, your code is checking for error conditions, but continuing on, as if the data is OK

By adding `return` before the call to `reject`, you'll stop this from happening

Just the area of code with changes shown:

```
      // snip
      if (err) {
        return reject(new Error(err))
      }

      if (parsed.feed.entries.length === 0) {
        return reject(new Error('Nothing to parse'))
      }

      const link = parsed.feed.entries[0].link
      const betterLink = link.substring(42, link.indexOf('&ct='))
      //snip
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides, what Jaramonda suggested, you're also using an anti-pattern when you have a promise and you do resolve and reject in both paths.  You can do that much more efficiently:

```
  resolve(mercury.parse(betterLink));
```

But, what you really should do is you should promisify `parser.parseURL()` so you can write all the control flow logic using promises.  This is much more foolproof and creates a reusable interface that uses promises that you can use elsewhere:

```
// make promisified version of parser.parseURL()
parser.parseURLP = function (url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parser.parseURL(url, (err, parsed) => {
            if (err) return reject(new Error(err));
            resolve(parsed);
        });
    });
};

function parseReporter() {
    return parser.parseURL(`https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/${this.googleAlertsUrlId}/${this.reporterUrlId}`).then(parsed => {
        if (parsed.feed.entries.length === 0) {
            throw new Error('Nothing to parse');
        }

        const link = parsed.feed.entries[0].link
        const betterLink = link.substring(42, link.indexOf('&ct='))

        return mercury.parse(betterLink).catch(err => {
            // wrap error in Error object
            throw new Error(err);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying `ParseError: Unexpected Token` at the `=` of `parse.parseURLP`.

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes - Just a typo.  It should be `parser.parseURLP = `.

Comment: Still, the first dot is accused to have an error, and also the opening curly bracket of the following method, and both saying `;` is missing. I am using AdonisJS.

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes - I'd have to see your actual code in order to know what is wrong with it.  This sounds like syntax errors in the code.  If that is not something you can figure out, then I can only help if I can see the whole relevant section of code including what is right before and after the position of the error.